# Aluminium tubing strength - size/thickness v length for supporting its own weight

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, structural-analysis

I want to make a simple fruit picker for a tall fig tree.  Most of the fruit is lost as it drops when ripe and explodes on impact with the ground below.  That or the birds get to it before we do!

So my thoughts are of a simple length of aluminium tubing, with a picker on the end and small catching net below.  Doesn't need to be telescopic or anything like that as we have room to store it at full length.  This would be in the region of 6m or maybe up to 8m.

So what size tubing would I require to support the weight of the tubing (plus maybe an extra half a kilo of fruit at a time in the net at the end?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Most places stock tubing in standard length of 6m, shorter a it needs to be cut and longer welded. Although its possible to get longer from the manufacturer. So i suggest staying at 6 meters. Although its cerainly useful if the last 2 meters would have smaller dia. In fact a tapered tube would be great but cost could be an issue

Comment: Do consider that the tube will need to be able to support more than its own mass...

Comment: One - get an aluminum step-ladder, Two, prune heck out of the tallest trunks next winter.  Figs bear better with pruning.

Comment: vertical or horizontal - makes a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Find a swimming pool net and use that pole for your construction. A tree pruning hook attached ought to work quite well.

Aluminium may not seem heavy until you start messing with lengths like 6m or more.

Here is a link [pool net](https://www.fruugo.co.uk/heavy-duty-pool-net-for-cleaning-leaves-debris-for-cleaning-leaves-debris/p-87130417-181736923?language=en&ac=bing&msclkid=b53d06b32cc31ed21446644e5652974b)